# Getting fault address from System.AccessViolationException

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I'm trying to debug a C++/CLI application that's causing a memory violation using Visual Studio 2010.

When I attach the debugger as only "Native", I see the address the program tried to access which triggered the fault, but I don't see any information for C++/CLI code.

When I attach as mixed Managed/Native, I get "System.AccessViolationException was unhandled" and a stack trace, but I can't find the address that actually caused the fault. Is there any way to see this in the Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: Neither the dialog nor the stack trace shows the address, the debugger favors the "how did it get this bad" view.  This is not supposed to happen in managed code.  Use Debug > Windows > Disassembly, it shows the address.

Comment: @HansPassant: No it doesn't? I can see which instruction I'm on, but not the address being accessed that actually caused the fault. I can assume what it is based on the disassembly, but it doesn't show me 100% what the OS thinks the faulting address is.

Comment: That can only happen when the fault occurs in managed code.  Bad place to be, for one the address is useless because it will never be the same, jitted code always ends up at a random address.  Is there any point left in knowing the address?